# Я не понимаю, по какой логике отображаются знаки во вкладке "Выберите ваш следующий знак"

Tags: поддержка, знаки, нытьё

Есть некоторые знаки не за метки, которые можно выбирать, как отслеживаемые.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только почему-то тут не все знаки, которые есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).
Я пыталась разгадать логику, как они туда отбираются и не поняла. Сначала думала, что там только те, которые можно получить всего 1 раз. Но **смотритель** и **инспектор** не вписываются в эту теорию (смотритель есть, а инспектора нет). Ещё думала, что там только те, для которых у тебя достаточно репутации, чтобы их получить. Но у меня там **смотритель**, а очередь проверок мне не доступна, при этом у меня уже есть **кворум** и **годовалый**, а там их нет и не было, и в "поиск знака..." они не находятся.

Я даже не знаю, `дефект` это или `так-задумано`, но поскольку я хочу отслеживать, сколько у меня по просмотрам вопросов (`Популярный вопрос`) и ссылок (`Диктор`), но не могу, пускай это будет `нытьё`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Там нет знаков, вычисление прогресса по которым требует больших вычислительных ресурсов. Такие знаки обычно вообще не отслеживаются.

И ещё предполагаю, что там каждый знак только один раз, т. е. если он уже получен, то больше не предлагается.

А вообще, кажется, там только знаки, дающие доступ к некой функциональности сайта. Ну или знаки за метки.

Лично у меня там только знаки за метки.

Comment: Профиль > активность > сводка. Так две кробоки "знаки" и "репутация". У меня в каждой шестерёнка и в "репутации" только метки, а в "знаки" меток нет - это то что на скрине.

Comment: А разве знаки дают доступ к функциональности, если они не за метки? Их же репутация даёт вроде